# Showing a measure on a locally compact group is left invariant

Tags: measure-theory, locally-compact-groups

I am trying to verify that the measure $\frac{1}{|x|}dx$ is a Haar measure on $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$.

For every open interval $(a_{n},b_{n})\subset \mathbb{R}$ not containing $0$, I have that the measure of $(a_{n},b_{n})$ is given by $$\int_{a_{n}}^{b_{n}}\frac{1}{|x|}dx = \ln(b) - \ln(a)$$

and thus the measure $x(a_{n},b_{n})$ is

$$\int_{xa_{n}}^{xb_{n}}\frac{1}{|x|}dx = \ln(xb) - \ln(xa) = \ln(b) - \ln(a)$$

Since the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ are generated by such open intervals, am I done?  Or do I still have to consider arbitrary Borel sets?

Comment: That depends on what you are allowed to use; but assuming you already know that this is a measure, then yes, this is enough. If you need to check uniqueness, then you probably need to appeal to Caratheodory's conditions and what-not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the following approach works to extend properties to $\sigma$-algebras.

First, prove that the property holds for all the generators of the $\sigma$-algebra$.

Second, prove that the collection of elements for which the property holds is a $\sigma$-algebra.